# How can I know what OS I'm working in?

Tags: c++, c

I need a function that can clear the screen in both Linux and Windows. To do this, I want to know if there are some instructions that can tell me what operating system I'm working with.
I have searched for solution and I found the following code:

```
void clear_screen()
{
   #ifdef WINDOWS

    std::system ( "CLS" );

    #else

    // Assume POSIX

    std::system("clear");

    #endif
}
```

There are two problems with this function:

- I don't understand it.

  -> for `#ifdef WINDOWS`, where is WINDOWS defined?
- This code works in Linux but it doesn't work in Windows.

*Note :*

- I'm using Windows XP.
- I don't want any non-standard functionality ... such "curses"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for

```
// Windows, all variants (including 64-bit and ARM)
#ifdef _WIN32
```

or

```
#ifdef __unix__
```

These are defined by your compiler, and are not stored in a header file. Because of that, you don't need to `#include` a file first, and these `#ifdef`s will always give the correct result (unless you mess with the compiler)

Comment: +1 but you should probably also address the second part the question "Where are these being defined"

Comment: thx ... but is '_WIN32' for any Windows version (XP,Vista,7,8) 32 and 64 bit !!

Comment: @BBeta for every windows with more than 16 bit, since you don't list MS DOS you should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

Macros such as `_WIN32`, `__gnu_linux__`, `__linux__` are defined by the compiler in question.  You can find a comprehensive list of pre-defined compiler macros [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/).

`_WIN32` is defined for both 32-bit and 64-bit environments of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

`WINDOWS` is defined by your compiler, so this defines can be compiler-dependant. It's usefull in order to compile specific code depending on your OS.

Answer (score 1):

There are various compiler-dependant macros. Unfortunately, they are not particularly useful, because they are not standardized and a C compiler for a particular OS does not necessarily #define them. I also suspect that they actually violate the C standard C11 7.1.3.

The 100% portable solution, which will compile on all C compilers, is to create such a constant yourself. Since C is a compiled language, you will have to compile your code differently for each OS anyhow. Simply add a file called `os.c` where you put a relevant `#define` or constant, then link this to your program. The only thing you need to change when compiling for a different OS is the make file path to your OS-specific `os.c`.